# how to set next page option in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

Json data which i receive from webservice is

```
{"meta": {"limit": 20, "next": "/api/un_bn_in/?offset=20&limit=20&format=json", "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 439603}, "objects": [{"id": 1, "phrase": "this is bengali test", "resource_uri": "/api/un_bn_in/1/", "verified_by_admin": true, "verified_by_usr": true}] }
```

To go next page url is "/api/un_bn_in/?offset=20&limit=20&format=json"

My jsonreader function is as follows:-

```
jsonReader{
    id : "id",
    repeatitems: false,
    root: function (obj) { return obj.objects; },
    records: function (obj) { 
          return 20; },
    total: function (obj) { return obj.meta.total_count; 
}
```

The real problem here is when i press next page button url generated by jqgrid is 
/api/un_bn_in/?format=json&_search=false&nd=1383576507420&rows=20&page=1&sidx=id&sord=asc

But i want "/api/un_bn_in/?offset=20&limit=20&format=json" this url to be generated so that i can get next page

Any help on this issue will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [prmNames](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) option of jqGrid to rename standard jqGrid options or to remove some other. For example the option

```js
prmNames: {nd: null, search: null, sort: null, order: null, rows: "limit" }
```

will remove some parameters which you don't need and rename `rows` option to `limit`. You will get the URL like `/api/un_bn_in/?format=json&limit=20&page=2`. The last step would be replacing `limit` and `page` options to `/api/un_bn_in/?format=json0&limit=20&offset=20`. In the case you can use `serializeGridData` additionally. The resulting options could be about the following

```js
url: "/api/un_bn_in/?format=json",
prmNames: {nd: null, search: null, sort: null, order: null, rows: "limit" },
serializeGridData: (postData) {
    return {
        limit: postData.limit,
        offset: (parseInt(postData.page, 10) - 1) * postData.limit
    };
}
```